# Лучший способ сохранить состояние кнопок

Tags: android, анимация

Есть `TextView` (вместо `Buttons`), которые анимируются - меняют позицию при нажатии на них, но при перерисовке активности (ротация), все конечно же возвращается на свои места. Как сохранить послеанимационное состояние?
 Сейчас после ротации вызывается метод `performClick()` с нулевой длительностью анимации,но это больше походит на костыль.

Comment: в голову пока пришел вариант get и затем set оси Х,хотя бы не костыль, а тросточка  просто

Answer (score 1):

Что бы сохранять позицию при вращении экрана вам нужно сохранять состояние в savedInstanseState потому как активити попросту пересоздается при повороте.
Коротко об этом можно почитать тут http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/133-urok-70-onsaveinstancestate-sohranenie-dannyh-activity-pri-povorote-ekrana.html

Comment: это все уже есть,в сооствествии с состоянием кнопки(анимировалась/в исходном положении) я и вызываю(или нет) метод performClick(),ну вот и спрашваю,есть ли способ сохранить состояние самой анимации. Учитывая,что это ObjectAnimator,то можно записать текущее(на момент переворачивания) время,но это лишнее,так как визуально не особо отличается от отсутсвия таких манипуляций,тем более что это не решает проблему - все равно нужно вызывать performClick,а я ищу более элегантный способ сохранить состояние